# How to avoid same object from an array in a row when fetching?

Tags: reactjs

I fetch a random object from the array but i dont want to get the same object twice in a row.

import { useState } from 'react'
import '../styles/GetData.css'

```
const GetData = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([])

  const FetchData = () => {
    fetch('facts.json', {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Accept: 'application/json'
      }
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((result) => {
        const random = result.facts
        const randomFact = random[Math.floor(Math.random() * random.length)]
        console.log('Randomfact', randomFact)
        setData(randomFact)
      })
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div className='btn'>
        <button onClick={FetchData}>Get Random Fact</button>
      </div>
      <h2>{data.text}</h2>
    </div>
  )
}
export default GetData
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the new randomFact with the old data and call the fonction again if it match :

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const FetchData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(
      "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/",
      {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Accept: "application/json"
        }
      }
    );
    const result = await response.json();
    const smallResult = result.slice(0, 2);

    let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * smallResult.length);
    let randomFact = smallResult[randomIndex];
    console.log("Randomfact", randomFact);

    if (randomFact.id === data.id && smallResult.length > 1) {
      await FetchData();
    } else {
      setData(randomFact);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => FetchData()}>Get random Fact</button>
      <h1>{data.title}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Or it 'll be better to just get an other id without fetching in a loop :

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const FetchData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(
      "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/",
      {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Accept: "application/json"
        }
      }
    );
    const result = await response.json();
    const smallResult = result.slice(0, 2);

    let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * smallResult.length);
    let randomFact = smallResult[randomIndex];
    console.log("Randomfact", randomFact);

    if (randomFact.id === data.id && smallResult.length > 1) {
      let newRandomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * smallResult.length)
      while (newRandomIndex === randomIndex) {
        newRandomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * smallResult.length);
      }
      randomFact = smallResult[newRandomIndex]
    }
    setData(randomFact);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => FetchData()}>Get random Fact</button>
      <h1>{data.title}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I tested the two edited version in codesandbox and it works, i hope it help you